# How do I download entire human genome for local blast formatting and searching?

Tags: blast, ncbi

I'm trying to make a copy of the entire human genome for local blast queries on my machine.  I understand that I need to download it from the NCBI FTP server here...

ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens

After downloading it I need to format it into a database that blast can search.  I do this using NCBI's makeformatdb command.  It is run like this...

```
makeblastdb -in entire_human_genome.fasta -dbtype nucl -title human_genome -out human_genome.db
```

My question is...  Where do I get the fasta file containing the entire human genome?  Do I download the fasta files for all 22 chromosomes, the X chromosome, and then the Y chromosome and concatenate them?  Is there a fasta file on the site containing the entire genome?  A fasta file that is not partitioned by chromosome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either download and concatenate the individual chromosomes from NCBI or make your life easier and download a single fasta file [from Gencode](ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_human/release_26/GRCh38.primary_assembly.genome.fa.gz) (note that that's the primary assembly, if you want the one with haplotypes then [it's here](ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/gencode/Gencode_human/release_26/GRCh38.p10.genome.fa.gz)).

Having written all of that, the "human_genomic" files on the [NCBI FTP server](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/) are the prebuilt blast databases for humans.

Comment: Just had a look at the prebuilt blast databases you linked to.  I would want the one named "human_genomic_transcript.tar.gz".  That is the largest one at 6.0 GB.  Is this the complete genome?

Comment: You probably want the 21 `human_genomic.??.tar.gz` files. They each contain subsets of the whole database. The `human_genomic_transcript.tar.gz` file is a superset of that, additionally containing refseq transcripts. See more details [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK62345/).